# adding text to file, results in invalid utf-8 encoding, and fail compilation on macos

Tags: python, macos, unicode, utf-8, compiler-errors

I'm using `macOS Big Sur 11.4`, i attempt to edit a .c file and add some logic to it, then compile it with a `setup.py` file which looks like that:

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension

module1 = Extension('myfile',
                    sources = ['myfile.c'],
                    extra_link_args = ['-framework', 'IOKit'])

setup (name = 'myfile',
       version = '0.1.1',
       description = 'test',
       ext_modules = [module1])
```

the file im trying to edit (`myfile.c`) will later be compiled and installed using the command line: `python setup.py install`. So far pretty straight forward.

When i'm editing any part of the code, even adding a simple comment like so: `//test` to my .c file, when attempting compilation i'm receiving:

```
...
myfile.c:625:16: error: source file is not valid UTF-8
<U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><F8><FF><FF><FF><FF><FF><FF>
...
warning: null character ignored [-Wnull-character]
# 1 "<built-in>" 3
...
error: source file is not valid UTF-8
...
```

The amount of `<U+0000>` is equal to the amount of letters i added, spaces, letters, etc...

Removing the line i've added "resolves" the UTF-8 coding problems.
Things i've attempted which did not work:

- I'm using pycharm to edit the file, so change file encoding from `File > File Properties > File Encoding` I've tried several different encodings (uncluding UTF-8). none worked
- To make sure its not a pycharm issue, i've also attempted editing the code in XCode, and VIM, both resulted in the same error

I get the feeling that something is wrong with the input from my keyboard, but i'm not sure what or why. Its worth mentioning that i've edited that file in the past using PyCharm and I had no problems.

Edit:
I've checked the file hexdump using xxd, and everything looks regular actually, I don't see unicode characters in the hex dump

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I didnt completely resolved it, but I found a work around, also i've forgot to mention something important here
I was actually compiling from a VM, through a VM shared folder (VMware Fusion)
while coding on my host computer.

anyways, instead of using the share, i copied the file using `scp` and then i had no encoding problems... not completely resolved issue, but for now I can live with that.